# How to write a variable by replacing the letter of an other variable by one place in Python?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm having trouble with this script.
I need to write this word by replacing all the other letter by one place.

```
def replace_word(word):

    letter = list(word)
    i = 0
    final_letter = letter[0]
    guess = ""

    while i + 1 < len(word):

        guess = letter[i + 1]

        final_letter += guess
        i += 1

    print(final_letter)
replace_word("hhello")
```

My goal is to have in the variable `final_letter == "hello"`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It seems your code just copies the letters from the original to the final word. Is the code supposed to remove duplicate letters?

Comment: According to your description your function could simply be `def replace_word(word): print(word[1:])`

Comment: Your question is incoherent and appears to be asking us to do your homework assignment. The phrase "replacing all the other letter by one place" doesn't mean anything in english. Are you trying to shift all the letters left one character? With or without wraparound? The trivial solution, as @Sunitha noted in their answer, is to just do `print(word[1:])` to ignore the first character (which is what your solution currently does).

Comment: the question is not clear can you please make it more clear, it seems that the question is about removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the line `final_letter = letter[0]` to `final_letter = ''` your code would exactly do what you want it to do

```
def replace_word(word):

    letter = list(word)
    i = 0
    final_letter = ''
    guess = ""

    while i + 1 < len(word):

        guess = letter[i + 1]

        final_letter += guess
        i += 1

    print(final_letter)
```

That being said, you could achieve the same by doing something as simple as this

```
def replace_word(word):
    print(word[1:])
```